# Ajax reload data chat.js showing error on mouse hover on graph

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Please Run code snippet.

When I click on reload button and move mouse on the the chart. The graph changing it's data and color. It showing previous data chart.

Anyone help me to solve this problem. I don't know how to solve it.

```js
$('documnet').ready(function(){
     $('#reload').on("click",function(){
      piechart();
     });
    
  piechart();  

function piechart(){

// Pie chart or doughnut chart with chart.js

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");

var data = [
     { value: 300, color:"#F7464A", highlight: "#FF5A5E", label: "sample" },
] ;

// data is empty. 
// we'll thow in between 10 and 50 items randomly generated

entries = 10 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 40);

for (i = 0; i < entries; i++) {
    r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 200);
    g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 200);
    b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 200);
    v = Math.floor(Math.random() * 500);
    c = 'rgb(' + r + ', ' + g + ', ' + b + ')';
    h = 'rgb(' + (r+20) + ', ' + (g+20) + ', ' + (b+20) + ')';
    data.push( {
      value : v,
      label : 'item ' + i,
      color: c,
      highlight: h
    }) ;
};
var options = { } ;

if ( entries % 2 ) {
var myChart = new Chart(ctx).Doughnut(data,options);
}
else {
var myChart = new Chart(ctx).Doughnut(data,options);
}
    
}
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.min.js"></script>

<button id="reload">Reload</button>

<canvas id="myChart" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
```

enter code here

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to have different name for canvas and your doughnut-chart. If you keep your doughnut-chart name as "myChart",try:

```
function piechart(){
myChart.destroy();
// Pie chart or doughnut chart with chart.js
```

Comment: You'd also need a `var myChart` in the parent scope and a `if (myChart)` before the destroy() call. Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following code:

```
$('#myChart').replaceWith('<canvas id="myChart" width="600" height="400"></canvas>');
```

Comment: I strongly suggest expanding on your current answer with some explanation on how/why it solves the problem. That would make it more useful to the OP and future readers.